# jQuery 1.8.0 to 1.8.1 incompatibility with .on() selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

We just stumbled across an imcompatibility between the two jQuery versions which is breaking one of our applications. The problem came up when updating from 1.7 to the latest 2.1 version, but was narrowed down to a difference between 1.8.0 and 1.8.1.

I've built a fiddle [here (1.8.0, working)](http://jsfiddle.net/92k8fke5/3/) and [here (1.8.1, broken)](http://jsfiddle.net/92k8fke5/4/).

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="eventcontext">
        <a href="#targetNope" class="hasevent">Click me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.eventcontext').on('click', '.outer a.hasevent', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('#targetYep').show();
});
```

In 1.8.0 using a selector that matches the desired elements, with part of the selector being "above" the events context works without any problems, the same way the native `querySelector` does, while in 1.8.1 it does not.

Was this an intentional change or can we expect this to be "fixed" at some point? I'm wondering if this might be a bug, as it happened in a patch version update, breaks stuff (at least in our case), but is still the same in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery 1.8.1 Change Log](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/):

```
Events:    #12383: jQuery.on() selector should only apply to descendants of the element
```

So when you remove `.outer` from selector it works.

Also working because selector is descendant of element that handles the click:

```
$('.outer').on('click', '.eventcontext a.hasevent', function(e) { /**/ });
$('.outer').on('click', 'a.hasevent', function(e) { /**/ });
```

Guessed reason for the change: The old versions had to search the whole document to find elements matched by the selector, which is slow. And for event-delegation it doesn't make sense to search **outside** the element that handles the event.

Comment: The performance reason makes sense! I will still take a look at the jQuery source some time to see what exactly is going on. As mentioned, `querySelector` does work in that case, so if they're using that under the hood Sizzle would have to do extra work to get this behaviour. Thanks for your answer and for pointing out that line on the changelog! I must have missed that.